# Splitting a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the following statement.

For every sequence $x_1, x_2, \dots$ of nonnegative real numbers there exist two sequences $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots$ of nonnegative real numbers such that:

- $x_n=a_n+b_n$ for all $n$
- $a_1+\ldots+a_k\le k$ for infinitely many $k$
- $b_1+\ldots+b_h\le h$ for infinitely many $h$.

Comment: It isn't true for $x_{n} = 2^n$.

Comment: @Harold:  yes it is.  I fooled myself for a while, too.

Comment: Oh, yes. The problem is actually extremely easy, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  if $a_1=0$ then you get one $k$ that works.  Then you must have $b_1=x_n$.  What is the first $h$ that may work?  Then what is the next possibility for $k$ that works?

Comment: 1) $a_1=0$ and $b_1=x_1$
2) $a_i=x_i$ and $b_i=0$ with $i\in\{2,\ldots, x_1\}$
3) $a_i=0$ and $b_i=x_i$ with $i\in\{x_1+1, \ldots, x_2+\ldots +x_{x_1}\}$
and so on...
Right?

Comment: @user72870: you have it